# Built in Luis location entity is not working correctly

Tags: entity, botframework, azure-language-understanding, built-in

I have a LUIS built in location entity, and I am getting the location using this code:

```
if (result.TryFindEntity("builtin.geographyV2.countryRegion", out rec)) {
    location = rec.Resolution.Values.ToString();
}
```

After getting the location the control goes to completion method of the LUIS dialog

```
private async Task ResumeAftelLuisDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result) {
    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

The same code is working fine with a custom entity.

Why does the builtin LUIS entity behave like this?

Comment: Could you please provide specific sample value of "entity that is working" and "entity that is not working"?

Comment: Does LUIS correctly identify the entity outside of your bot/code/dialog? (in LUIS test panel for example) If not, you may have hit a known issue where geographyV2 doesn't correctly identify the location.

Comment: Application identify and give the correct value of entity but after getting value the control goes to ResumeAftelLuisDialog method which should be called once the task is complete. The bot work properly if we work on custum location entity.

Comment: Add more details about your implementation and values so that we can test and help